# View components in model (MVC)?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, view, model

In a MVC application, can the model hold view components (e.g. javafx.scene.image.Image)? I was told the model should not be tied to any view components because it was meant to be reusable. It makes sense but I have a case in which it is kind of difficult to respect that rule.

Basically I am building a card game with a GUI using JavaFX. This is what the card class in the model looks like:

```
package model;

/**
 * Created by 1232170 on 2014-11-24.
 */
public enum Card {
    // @formatter:off
    ACE_OF_CLUBS      ("Ace of Clubs",      Rank.ACE,   Suit.CLUBS,    "A\u2663",  "\uD83C\uDCD1"),
    ACE_OF_DIAMONDS   ("Ace of Diamonds",   Rank.ACE,   Suit.DIAMONDS, "A\u2666",  "\uD83C\uDCC1"),
    ACE_OF_HEARTS     ("Ace of Hearts",     Rank.ACE,   Suit.HEARTS,   "A\u2665",  "\uD83C\uDCB1"),
    ACE_OF_SPADES     ("Ace of Spades",     Rank.ACE,   Suit.SPADES,   "A\u2660",  "\uD83C\uDCA1"),
    EIGHT_OF_CLUBS    ("Eight of Clubs",    Rank.EIGHT, Suit.CLUBS,    "8\u2663",  "\uD83C\uDCD8"),
    EIGHT_OF_DIAMONDS ("Eight of Diamonds", Rank.EIGHT, Suit.DIAMONDS, "8\u2666",  "\uD83C\uDCC8"),
    EIGHT_OF_HEARTS   ("Eight of Hearts",   Rank.EIGHT, Suit.HEARTS,   "8\u2665",  "\uD83C\uDCB8"),
    EIGHT_OF_SPADES   ("Eight of Spades",   Rank.EIGHT, Suit.SPADES,   "8\u2660",  "\uD83C\uDCA8"),
    FIVE_OF_CLUBS     ("Five of Clubs",     Rank.FIVE,  Suit.CLUBS,    "5\u2663",  "\uD83C\uDCD5"),
    FIVE_OF_DIAMONDS  ("Five of Diamonds",  Rank.FIVE,  Suit.DIAMONDS, "5\u2666",  "\uD83C\uDCC5"),
    FIVE_OF_HEARTS    ("Five of Hearts",    Rank.FIVE,  Suit.HEARTS,   "5\u2665",  "\uD83C\uDCB5"),
    FIVE_OF_SPADES    ("Five of Spades",    Rank.FIVE,  Suit.SPADES,   "5\u2660",  "\uD83C\uDCA5"),
    FOUR_OF_CLUBS     ("Four of Clubs",     Rank.FOUR,  Suit.CLUBS,    "4\u2663",  "\uD83C\uDCD4"),
    FOUR_OF_DIAMONDS  ("Four of Diamonds",  Rank.FOUR,  Suit.DIAMONDS, "4\u2666",  "\uD83C\uDCC4"),
    FOUR_OF_HEARTS    ("Four of Hearts",    Rank.FOUR,  Suit.HEARTS,   "4\u2665",  "\uD83C\uDCB4"),
    FOUR_OF_SPADES    ("Four of Spades",    Rank.FOUR,  Suit.SPADES,   "4\u2660",  "\uD83C\uDCA4"),
    JACK_OF_CLUBS     ("Jack of Clubs",     Rank.JACK,  Suit.CLUBS,    "J\u2663",  "\uD83C\uDCDB"),
    JACK_OF_DIAMONDS  ("Jack of Diamonds",  Rank.JACK,  Suit.DIAMONDS, "J\u2666",  "\uD83C\uDCCB"),
    JACK_OF_HEARTS    ("Jack of Hearts",    Rank.JACK,  Suit.HEARTS,   "J\u2665",  "\uD83C\uDCBB"),
    JACK_OF_SPADES    ("Jack of Spades",    Rank.JACK,  Suit.SPADES,   "J\u2660",  "\uD83C\uDCAB"),
    KING_OF_CLUBS     ("King of Clubs",     Rank.KING,  Suit.CLUBS,    "K\u2663",  "\uD83C\uDCDE"),
    KING_OF_DIAMONDS  ("King of Diamonds",  Rank.KING,  Suit.DIAMONDS, "K\u2666",  "\uD83C\uDCCE"),
    KING_OF_HEARTS    ("King of Hearts",    Rank.KING,  Suit.HEARTS,   "K\u2665",  "\uD83C\uDCBE"),
    KING_OF_SPADES    ("King of Spades",    Rank.KING,  Suit.SPADES,   "K\u2660",  "\uD83C\uDCAE"),
    NINE_OF_CLUBS     ("Nine of Clubs",     Rank.NINE,  Suit.CLUBS,    "9\u2663",  "\uD83C\uDCD9"),
    NINE_OF_DIAMONDS  ("Nine of Diamonds",  Rank.NINE,  Suit.DIAMONDS, "9\u2666",  "\uD83C\uDCC9"),
    NINE_OF_HEARTS    ("Nine of Hearts",    Rank.NINE,  Suit.HEARTS,   "9\u2665",  "\uD83C\uDCB9"),
    NINE_OF_SPADES    ("Nine of Spades",    Rank.NINE,  Suit.SPADES,   "9\u2660",  "\uD83C\uDCA9"),
    QUEEN_OF_CLUBS    ("Queen of Clubs",    Rank.QUEEN, Suit.CLUBS,    "Q\u2663",  "\uD83C\uDCDD"),
    QUEEN_OF_DIAMONDS ("Queen of Diamonds", Rank.QUEEN, Suit.DIAMONDS, "Q\u2666",  "\uD83C\uDCCD"),
    QUEEN_OF_HEARTS   ("Queen of Hearts",   Rank.QUEEN, Suit.HEARTS,   "Q\u2665",  "\uD83C\uDCBD"),
    QUEEN_OF_SPADES   ("Queen of Spades",   Rank.QUEEN, Suit.SPADES,   "Q\u2660",  "\uD83C\uDCAD"),
    SEVEN_OF_CLUBS    ("Seven of Clubs",    Rank.SEVEN, Suit.CLUBS,    "7\u2663",  "\uD83C\uDCD7"),
    SEVEN_OF_DIAMONDS ("Seven of Diamonds", Rank.SEVEN, Suit.DIAMONDS, "7\u2666",  "\uD83C\uDCC7"),
    SEVEN_OF_HEARTS   ("Seven of Hearts",   Rank.SEVEN, Suit.HEARTS,   "7\u2665",  "\uD83C\uDCB7"),
    SEVEN_OF_SPADES   ("Seven of Spades",   Rank.SEVEN, Suit.SPADES,   "7\u2660",  "\uD83C\uDCA7"),
    SIX_OF_CLUBS      ("Six of Clubs",      Rank.SIX,   Suit.CLUBS,    "6\u2663",  "\uD83C\uDCD6"),
    SIX_OF_DIAMONDS   ("Six of Diamonds",   Rank.SIX,   Suit.DIAMONDS, "6\u2666",  "\uD83C\uDCC6"),
    SIX_OF_HEARTS     ("Six of Hearts",     Rank.SIX,   Suit.HEARTS,   "6\u2665",  "\uD83C\uDCB6"),
    SIX_OF_SPADES     ("Six of Spades",     Rank.SIX,   Suit.SPADES,   "6\u2660",  "\uD83C\uDCA6"),
    TEN_OF_CLUBS      ("Ten of Clubs",      Rank.TEN,   Suit.CLUBS,    "10\u2663", "\uD83C\uDCDA"),
    TEN_OF_DIAMONDS   ("Ten of Diamonds",   Rank.TEN,   Suit.DIAMONDS, "10\u2666", "\uD83C\uDCCA"),
    TEN_OF_HEARTS     ("Ten of Hearts",     Rank.TEN,   Suit.HEARTS,   "10\u2665", "\uD83C\uDCBA"),
    TEN_OF_SPADES     ("Ten of Spades",     Rank.TEN,   Suit.SPADES,   "10\u2660", "\uD83C\uDCAA"),
    THREE_OF_CLUBS    ("Three of Clubs",    Rank.THREE, Suit.CLUBS,    "3\u2663",  "\uD83C\uDCD3"),
    THREE_OF_DIAMONDS ("Three of Diamonds", Rank.THREE, Suit.DIAMONDS, "3\u2666",  "\uD83C\uDCC3"),
    THREE_OF_HEARTS   ("Three of Hearts",   Rank.THREE, Suit.HEARTS,   "3\u2665",  "\uD83C\uDCB3"),
    THREE_OF_SPADES   ("Three of Spades",   Rank.THREE, Suit.SPADES,   "3\u2660",  "\uD83C\uDCA3"),
    TWO_OF_CLUBS      ("Two of Clubs",      Rank.TWO,   Suit.CLUBS,    "2\u2663",  "\uD83C\uDCD2"),
    TWO_OF_DIAMONDS   ("Two of Diamonds",   Rank.TWO,   Suit.DIAMONDS, "2\u2666",  "\uD83C\uDCC2"),
    TWO_OF_HEARTS     ("Two of Hearts",     Rank.TWO,   Suit.HEARTS,   "2\u2665",  "\uD83C\uDCB2"),
    TWO_OF_SPADES     ("Two of Spades",     Rank.TWO,   Suit.SPADES,   "2\u2660",  "\uD83C\uDCA2");
    // @formatter:on

    private final String name;
    private final Rank rank;
    private final Suit suit;
    private final String unicode;
    private final String unicode2;

    private Card(String name, Rank rank, Suit suit, String unicode, String unicode2) {
        this.name = name;
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
        this.unicode = unicode;
        this.unicode2 = unicode2;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Rank getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public Suit getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public String getUnicode() {
        return unicode;
    }

    public String getUnicode2() {
        return unicode2;
    }

    public enum Rank {
        ACE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, KING, QUEEN, JACK;
    }

    public enum Suit {
        CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
        for (Card card : Card.values()) {
            System.out.println(card.getName());
            System.out.println(card.getRank());
            System.out.println(card.getSuit());
            System.out.println(card.getUnicode());
            System.out.println(card.getUnicode2());
            System.out.println();
        }
        */
    }
}
```

Should I just throw the card image in there too? Otherwise I would have to make another class in the View package with this long list to load the images, plus another long if-else in the controller to bind the correct image to the card. Or maybe I am simply overthinking?

Comment: *"can the model hold view components"* - No, never, nutta. You can come with all kinds of excuses why it might be okay, but it's not, you need to change your design, full stop.  Personally, I wouldn't call `Card` (in this case) a "model", it is data.  Personally, how the `Card` is rendered is the responsibility for the view...

Comment: Well the Card is not the model, but it is part of the model. It will be used by another class that will define the rules of the game etc. OK then I will keep the image in the View. Thanks.

Comment: No, you shouldn't include the image--for example, what if you wanted to have different deck themes? Instead, you have a list of images somewhere (maybe in a directory in your jar file) and match them to the names of the cards (maybe by naming them `QUEEN_OF_CLUBS.png`).

Comment: You'll likely connect the Card with Image via an `EnumMap<Card, Icon>` or something similar, but it should not be part of the Model.